# How to avoid plotting for a zero without deleting the zero entry in the line plot Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have tried a sample code where I used my figure to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l = [1.10867,1.10894,1.10914,1.10926,1.10930,0.00000,0.00000,0.00000,0.00000,0.00000,1.10867,1.10894,1.10914,1.10926,1.10930]
x = np.arange(len(l))
y = np.array(l)

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'r-') # Returns a tuple of line objects, thus the comma
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

The figure comes out to be the following:
[image: figure]
But I am expecting to have a figure this:
[image: expected output figure]

The expected figure is obtained when I removed the zeroes from the list. But I want to if there is a way to plot without removing zeroes from the list and still the figure looks like the expected one.

Please share any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpolate the points where y's are equal to 0 and plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l = [1.10867,1.10894,1.10914,1.10926,1.10930,0.00000,0.00000,0.00000,0.00000,0.00000,1.10867,1.10894,1.10914,1.10926,1.10930]
x = np.arange(len(l))
y = np.array(l)


y_interp = np.interp(x, x[np.where(y != 0)], y[np.where(y != 0)])
plt.plot(x, y_interp)
```

[image: Output plot]

Comment: @BigBen I guess the OP says : "The expected figure is obtained when I removed the zeroes from the list. But I want to if there is a way to plot without removing zeroes ...."